# Ubuntu 13.04 ATI graphics card and OpenGL issues

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, fglrx, opengl

### Problem

I am trying to run an OpenGL application which has worked on previous releases of Ubuntu on other machines but which happily opens windows crashes when I try and draw anything in them.

### System

- Ubuntu

  64 bit 
  Release: 13.04
- CPU

  ```
  processor   : 2
  vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
  cpu family  : 16
  model       : 4
  model name  : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 B95 Processor
  stepping    : 2
  microcode   : 0x10000db
  cpu MHz     : 800.000
  cache size  : 512 KB
  physical id : 0
  siblings    : 4
  core id     : 2
  cpu cores   : 4
  apicid      : 2
  initial apicid  : 2
  fpu     : yes
  fpu_exception   : yes
  cpuid level : 5
  wp      : yes
  ```
- Graphics

  01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]

### Troubleshooting

1. I downloaded `globs` and ran all the standard tests. They all worked properly except for GLSL_paralax which failed to even start.
2. I checked my graphics driver.

   ```
   glxinfo | grep render
   direct rendering: Yes
   OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880
   GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_AMD_conservative_depth,
   ```

   I understand this to mean that I am using the open source graphics driver and I am not using software rendering.
3. I ran `glxgears`

   ```
   glxgears -info
   Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
   approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.

   GL_RENDERER   = Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880
   GL_VERSION    = 3.0 Mesa 9.1.3
   GL_VENDOR     = X.Org

   ...

   301 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.155 FPS
   299 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.766 FPS
   298 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.566 FPS
   300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.968 FPS
   ```

   I think this is a bad result. Other sources said that I should have a much higher framerate, though my monitor is set at 60 Hz so if the render rate is set at that, it seems correct
4. I checked the OpenGL error log

   ```
    cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    [    14.665] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
    [    14.797] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
    [    14.832] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
   ```

   I think this means that I do not have the `fglrx` installed
5. I looked up what `fglrx` is and it appears that it is part of the proprietary OpenGL driver. Instructions on how to install it are found here: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Installing_Proprietary_Drivers_a.k.a._Catalyst.2Ffglrx

## Questions

1. Does anyone have any insight as to why the GLSL_paralax test failed to even start? Is there another comparable test I could try?
2. Are there other diagnostic tests I could perform to isolate my problems?
3. Is the missing `fglrx` module important? Could it be the source of my problems?
4. If so, can I get it without installing the proprietary driver?
5. If I need the proprietary driver, is the link I included the safest/easiest way to get it? I am loath to follow their instructions as I have had problems manually configuring the graphics driver of other Linux machines. Is there a graphical tool like Additional Drivers which could be used instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem however, the solution was that there was an unusual error in the openGL code I was running. It failed because it could not find the required fonts not because of graphical issues. Because of the way the c-based OGL and font calls were embedded into python code, this was difficult to track down.

In the process of discovering this I tried several things including upgrading to the proprietary graphics drivers. I would **Not** recommend this for anyone running an ATI HD graphics card which is not supported by the 13.04+ release of `fglrx`. You need to downgrade your Xserver and this makes unity run poorly. The proprietary drivers do not add much i could see to the system graphics, though many reported that they have advantages for laptops in terms of power consumption.

Finally, the `GLSL_paralax` test from `globs` failed for non driver-related reasons.

Overall, all graphics work on my system with the open source drivers.